# How to require select2 with webpacker/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I’ve been using select2 via CDN. I started migrating CDN to using the webpacker gem. I stumbled upon a difficulty, where I can’t import/require or in any way include it. So here is my setup:

I’ve migrated select2 via the following steps:

- yarn add select2

Below is my environment.js file (this is the configuration file, that webpacker uses to configure webpack):

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append(
    'Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
    })
)
module.exports = environment
```

environment.js

```
require("select2")
```

I tried all kinds of require and many others, but none of these seem to work. Please, advise. Thank you.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "none of these seem to work"? Do you see any errors on in the webpack output? Any errors on the dev tools console? Also, what's in your package.json file?

Comment: What's in your `config/webpacker.yml` file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's what I would check:

1. Install Webpacker in your Rails project properly, per the project README. If you're starting with a Rails 6 app, this will be done by default.
2. Add both `jquery` and `select2`:

   ```
   yarn add jquery select2
   ```
3. Add a select box to the DOM

   ```html
   <select class="js-states" name="state">
     <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
     ...
     <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
   </select>
   ```
4. Import jquery, select2 and select2 css and apply to the select box when the page is loaded:

   ```js
   import $ from 'jquery'
   import 'select2'
   import 'select2/dist/css/select2.css'

   window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
     $('.js-states').select2()
   })
   ```
5. For development, set `compile: true` in `config/webpacker.yml`. Running the `webpack-dev-server` is optional.

Those are the steps I took to create this demo: https://github.com/rossta/rails6-webpacker-demo/compare/example/select2

Comment: This works for me in development, but it doesn't work for me in production in Heroku.

Comment: Do you now how to enable the option to use select2 in the ruby js responds?

Comment: How do you make this work outside of `DOMContentLoaded` event listener